# how to find xpath in selenium webdriver when button webelement is dynamic

Tags: selenium, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Following is the html for the page and I need to get the xpath for the button which will work in selenium webdriver. or is there any way to click on the button in selenium webdriver
If its in java that would be great otherwise python and others languages are also appreciated.

```
<button style="" onclick="saveAndContinueEdit('http://192.168.1.99/cue_extensions/magento1.9/index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/back/edit/tab/{{tab_id}}/id/899/key/6ed7b01b3a2136d6ff896d9380e281d5/')" class="scalable save" type="button" title="Save and Continue Edit" id="**id_636f54090db18b58eecba78e9e6aa6b7**">
  <span><span><span>Save and Continue Edit</span></span></span>
</button>
```

but when next time i logged in the html changes to

```
<button style="" onclick="saveAndContinueEdit('http://192.168.1.99/cue_extensions/magento1.9/index.php/admin/catalog_product/save/back/edit/tab/{{tab_id}}/id/903/key/29d8597a8ec8f63d9b09addae444d4c0/')" class="scalable save" type="button" title="Save and Continue Edit" id="id_c2fe56a74ef2a166dcf0ae4ed7f8e391">
  <span><span><span>Save and Continue Edit</span></span></span>
</button>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Save and Continue Edit']")).click();
```

in python

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@title='Save and Continue Edit']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try the following:*

**In Java:**

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save and Continue Edit')]")).click();
```

**In Python:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Save and Continue Edit')]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the title is always "Save and Continue Edit" (i.e. the Magento backend language is not changed), use

```
//button[@title='Save and Continue Edit']
```

as suggested before. A more robust approach is to search by the `onclick` attribute, for example with:

```
//button[starts-with(@onclick,"saveAndContinueEdit(")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath -

```
//span[@title="Save and Continue Edit"]
```

Comment: No, you cannot, that is illegal XPath. Perhaps you meant `//*[@..]`, or `//span[@...]`? `\\` must always be followed by a NodeTest.

Answer (score 0):

In java you find using following command:

`driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//button[contains(.,'Save and Continue Edit')]")).click();`